# Close port 8080 on Mavericks

Tags: port, vagrant, osx-mavericks

I'm attempting to run Vagrantpress, which be default forwards the VM port 80 to the host port 8080. However, it reports that another application is using port 8080 and fails to boot.

Looking around, it seems that using something like `lsof | grep :8080` should list the application using the port. However, that command returns empty.

Using Mavericks' Network Utility > Port Scan I get this:

```
Port Scan has started…

Port Scanning host: 127.0.0.1

 Open TCP Port:     80          http
 Open TCP Port:     631         ipp
 Open TCP Port:     1023
 Open TCP Port:     3128        ndl-aas
 Open TCP Port:     5001        commplex-link
 Open TCP Port:     5003        fmpro-internal
 Open TCP Port:     5432        postgresql
 Open TCP Port:     8080        http-alt
 Open TCP Port:     20559
 Open TCP Port:     29754
 Open TCP Port:     49524
 Open TCP Port:     49525
Port Scan has completed…
```

But I can't figure out how to close http-alt so that the port can be used by another application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem and I have Cisco AnyConnect installed, which the answer on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66158/unkown-process-listening-at-port-8080 indicates could be the problem. I decided to change the port I was using instead of trying to get rid of the AnyConnect requirement so I can't verify that as a solution, but it's something to try.

Comment: I too had Cisco AnyConnect installed! That was most likely the culprit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should run `lsof -i :8080` instead of `lsof | grep :8080`, or `netstat -nap | grep :8080` (You may need to change the options on OS X as it is BSD), get the PID of the process and terminate / kill it.

If you just want to work around the issue, use `auto_correct: true` in the port forward block, for example

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080,
    auto_correct: true
end
```

and do a `vagrant reload`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this did not solve my problem. I'm not sure how to fix the options for netstat, but `lsof -i :8080` returned nothing.  Adding `auto_correct: true` does dance around the port collision by switching to `:2200`, but it's really no better than just changing the port number myself (which has been my solution manually).

This is also happening on two separate Mavericks boxes: I can't vagrant up using port 8080, but `lsof -i :8080` doesn't yield anything on both my desktop and laptop.

Comment: Try to run `lsof` and `netstat` using `sudo`, some system process may be running in the background and using the ports.